# Derivation of Chern-Simons invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

I am currently reading the original paper by Chern and Simons where they introduce their form. I am working out the examples, but I do not seem to be able to derive their formula. We should be able to derive:
 $$TP_1 (\theta) = \frac{1}{4 \pi ^2} (\theta_{12} \wedge \theta_{13}\wedge \theta_{23}+{\theta}_{12}\wedge\Omega_{12}+\theta_{13}\wedge\Omega_{13}+\theta_{23}\wedge\Omega_{23}) $$
The 3 Chern-Simons form for a 3-manifold.
We should only need the following equation applied to the case $l=2$ (since 3=2(2)-1):
$$TP(\theta) = \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} A_i P(\theta \wedge [\theta,\theta]^i\wedge\Omega^{l-i-1}) $$
$$ A_i = (-1)^i l! \frac{(l-1)!}{2^i (l+i)!} (l-1-i)!$$

My work:
I managed to reduce the formula to:
$$ TP_1(\theta)=P(\theta \wedge \Omega) - \frac{1}{6} P(\theta \wedge [\theta,\theta])$$
How do I express this last part in the local frame to get the desired formula? 
Also, I will be interested in calculating the higher degree forms. How do I work out the power of bracket and so?

Comment: The original formula should just be for $TP(\theta)$. You're then going to use the invariant polynomial $P=P_1$ on $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, which is $-\frac1{8\pi^2}\text{tr}(A^2)$. You have to polarize and get the formula Chern/Simons give with $P(A\otimes B) =-\frac1{8\pi^2}\text{tr}(AB)$. Note that when $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$, you get $\text{tr}(AB)=\sum a_{ij}b_{ij}$, which is pretty much their formula. (See also the appendix of Chern's Complex Manifolds book, second edition.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your answer. I get now how to work the $\theta \wedge \Omega$ term, but how do I calculate the bracket terms? I am especially interested in the cases where the formula gives me powers of the bracket.

Comment: Up possibly to a constant, you should think of $[\theta,\theta]$ just as the wedge product $\theta\wedge\theta$ of matrix-valued $1$-forms. In particular, $[\theta,\theta](X,Y) = [\theta(X),\theta(Y)]-[\theta(Y),\theta(X)] = 2[\theta(X),\theta(Y)]$, whereas $(\theta\wedge\theta)(X,Y) = \theta(X)\theta(Y)-\theta(Y)\theta(X)$, so $[\theta,\theta]=2\theta\wedge\theta$. You can check that $\text{tr}(\theta\wedge\theta\wedge\theta) = \sum \theta_{ij}\wedge\theta_{jk}\wedge\theta_{ki} = 6\theta_{12}\wedge\theta_{13}\wedge\theta_{23}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you very much!

Comment: You're most welcome. I don't quite get what you're trying to do with a $5$-manifold. $P_2$ lives in $H^8 = 0$, and the transgressive form $TP_2$ would be a $7$-form, still dead $0$ on a $5$-manifold.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, I'll edit the post.